# == operator with Strings

Tags: java, string

The code below should not print "Bye", since == operator is used to compare references, but oddly enough, "Bye" is still printed. Why does this happen? I'm using Netbeans 6.9.1 as the IDE.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String test ="Hi";
        if(test=="Hi"){
            System.out.println("Bye");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This behavior is because of **interning**. The behavior is described in the docs for [`String#intern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) (including why it's showing up in your code even though you never call `String#intern`):

> A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class `String`.
>
> When the `intern` method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this `String` object as determined by the `equals(Object)` method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this `String` object is added to the pool and a reference to this `String` object is returned.
>
> It follows that for any two strings `s` and `t`, `s.intern() == t.intern()` is `true` if and only if `s.equals(t)` is true.
>
> All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned. String literals are defined in §3.10.5 of the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/html/).

So for example:

```
public class Test {

    private String s1 = "Hi";

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        new Test().test();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void test() {
        String s2 ="Hi";
        String s3;

        System.out.println("[statics]          s2 == s1? " + (s2 == s1));
        s3 = "H" + part2();
        System.out.println("[before interning] s3 == s1? " + (s3 == s1));
        s3 = s3.intern();
        System.out.println("[after interning]  s3 == s1? " + (s3 == s1));
        System.exit(0);
    }

    protected String part2() {
        return "i";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[statics]          s2 == s1? true
[before interning] s3 == s1? false
[after interning]  s3 == s1? true
```

Walking through that:

1. The literal assigned to `s1` is automatically interned, so `s1` ends up referring to a string in the pool.
2. The literal assigned to `s2` is also auto-interned, and so `s2` ends up pointing to the same instance `s1` points to. This is fine even though the two bits of code may be completely unknown to each other, because Java's `String` instances are *immutable*. You can't change them. You can use methods like `toLowerCase` to get back a *new* string with changes, but the original you called `toLowerCase` (etc.) on remains unchanged. So they can safely be shared amongst unrelated code.
3. We create a *new* `String` instance via a runtime operation. Even though the new instance has the same sequence of characters as the interned one, it's a *separate* instance. The runtime doesn't intern dynamically-created strings automatically, because there's a cost involved: The work of finding the string in the pool. (Whereas when compiling, the compiler can take that cost onto itself.) So now we have two instances, the one `s1` and `s2` point to, and the one `s3` points to. So the code shows that `s3 != s1`.
4. Then we explicitly intern `s3`. Perhaps it's a large string we're planning to hold onto for a long time, and we think it's likely that it's going to be duplicated in other places. So we accept the work of interning it in return for the potential memory savings. Since interning by definition means we may get back a new reference, we assign the result back to `s3`.
5. And we can see that indeed, `s3` now points to the same instance `s1` and `s2` point to.

Comment: @Crowder also, does that mean that the explanation in this link is wrong? http://www.gtothesquare.com/2010/04/19/java-vs-equals/

Comment: @Ockhams: Glad that helped. Yes, the example in that link is wrong (had the author simply tried it, he/she would have known that), but only because the example uses literals and literals (and other constant string expressions) are automatically interned. The overall point of that post, that strings are objects and so if you want to compare them to see if they have the same characters you use `equals` rather than `==`, is correct. But certainly the example is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 10):

Hard-coded Strings are compiled into the JVM's String Table, which holds unique Strings - that is the compiler stores only one copy of "Hi", so you are comparing that *same object*, so `==` works.

If you actually create a new String using the constructor, like new `String("Hi")`, you *will* get a different object.

Answer (score 1):

There is a String cache in java. Where as in this case the same object is returned from the cache which hold the same reference.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for that is because the `"Hi"` is picked up from `String Pool`. The immutable object must have some sort of cache so it can perform better. So `String` class is immutable and it uses `String Pool` for basic cache.

In this case, `"Hi"` is in the String pool and all the String having values of `"Hi"` will have the same reference for String Pool.

Comment: Not always true. String constructor will always create a new String object.

Comment: `new String("Hi")` will be created on Heap and that will be whole new case. which is not discussed here. I Just explained that why == worked here. Thanks